# How to go to SecondViewController from RootViewController

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller, theos

I have search for hours with no good answers and it seems a lot of people have this issue... I am using theos on my iphone and I have a RootViewController with this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController.m" sender:nil];

}
```

There a table and a cell on the table name directions when its clicked I want it to display my SecondViewController.m, I honestly have no idea what or how to do this.

Comment: Is your segue really called "SecondViewController.m" ? Name your segue in the storyboard and use that name in the code. .m files are source files.

Comment: Really? I clearly stated im using theos there is no storyboard

Comment: Sorry I didn't saw (you should have state it more clearly somewhere else than in tag). Anyway, how your segue are created ? How they are named ? Segue is a transition in between two view controllers, so it can't be identified by such a name. If you haven't create segue, don't use them for transitions.

Comment: I have no idea how to go from my RootViewController to my SecondViewController by pressing a UIButton do you know how?

Comment: The preferred way is to use a `UINavigationController` and its method `pushViewController`, but you can simply use the `presentViewController` of any `UIViewController`.

Comment: But what would be the codes?

Comment: I gave you classes and methods...

Comment: I figured it out using a UIView

Comment: You told us about view controllers... Read the docs, there is `UIView`'s methods to manage the stack of views. (`addSubview:`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

performSegueWithIdentifier takes the name of a segue. It does not take the name of a view controller, and especially not the name of a file containing a view controller. It is intended for use with storyboards.

Take a look at UIViewController's presentViewController, or NavigationController's pushViewController if you have a navigation stack in your rvc.